# codeigniter data retrieve issue?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to retrieve data from a **table1** and I have to retrieve data from another table **table2** with foreign key of **table1** and display in views. How is it possible?

My controller is:

```
$data['products'] = $this->MProducts->getProducts($customer_id);
        foreach($data['products'] as $product){
            $cat_id = $product['category_id'];
            $data['category_name'] = $this->MCats->getCategoryById($cat_id);
        }
```

My view is:

```
foreach ($products as $list){
        echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";
        echo "<td align='center'>".$list['name']."</td>\n";

        echo "<td align='center'>".$category_name."</td>\n";
        echo "<td align='center'>";
        echo $list['status'];
        echo "</td>\n";

        echo "<td align='center'>".$list['marked_price']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td align='center'>".$list['discount_percent']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td align='center'>";
        echo anchor('products/partner/edit/'.$list['id'],'edit');
        echo " | ";
        echo anchor('products/partner/delete/'.$list['id'],'delete');
        echo "</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
```

In **$category_name** it gives the last value of category in all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about joins [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select).

But you would do something like:

```
$this->db->select('products.*, category.category_name');
$this->db->join('products', 'category.category_id = products.category_id');
$this->db->where('products.customer_id', $customer_id); // i guessed this part
$this->db->get('products');
```

// EDIT: also you have an mistake in your loop. It should look like this:

```
foreach($data['products'] as $key=>$product){
    $cat_id = $product['category_id'];
    $data['products'][$key]['category_name'] = $this->MCats->getCategoryById($cat_id);
}
```

then to should each products' category in your view use this:

```
echo "<td align='center'>".$list['category_name']."</td>\n";
```